Print data.frame to string without printing it to stdout
It is possible to store the output of print.data.frame() in a string:
s <- print(iris[1:2,], row.names=FALSE)

but this also prints the string to stdout. Is it possible to achieve the same without printing to stdout?

Are you looking for capture.output?

@jblood94 capture.output is indeed one way to solve this. Thanks.
